# VueJs Axios Access-Control-Allow-Origin CORS error

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios, cors, cors-anywhere

I make a website with Vue3 and Laravel 8. I try to use axios to post data from vue to laravel and i allways got CORS error. I tried everything and nothing work.
[You can check the error here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ebeu.jpg)

**Add header to axios**

```
addUser() {
      axios
        .post("http://localhost:8000/api/user/store", this.user, {
          headers: { "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*" }
        })
        .then(function (response) {
          console.log(response);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
        })
        .finally(() => (this.loading = false));
    },
```

**Add proxy to package.json**

```
"proxy": "http://127.0.0.1:8000",
```

**And tried this:**
https://enable-cors.org/server_apache.html

What can i do?

Comment: I don't know but part of the problem might be using both `localhost` and `127.0.0.1`, try using one or the other and it might fix the CORS issue. For instance does changing your axios.post to `http://127.0.0.1/api/user/store` work?

Comment: Yes, its work. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

`axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;`

to bootstrap.js